# Bootstrap Popover Full screen with Margin

Tags: html, css, angularjs, popover

I need a popover with full screen from Menu tabs with 30px margin from right & left side or I need a popover which need to open only in specific container width. I was just trying on specific div but its not working, please check on below fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/gzucny5o/

Comment: Adding CSS `margin: 0 30px;` to `.popover` isn't enough? Or what's the actual issue?

Comment: I tried this but popover is only shifting towards right & margin only apply to left.

Comment: It works when adding margin to the jsfiddle example. Can you please show your code? thanks

Comment: I will try to share my code, but do you have any example of popover which is open full screen with margin on it left right. Thanks.

Comment: I added margin in fiddle but still it's not working look https://jsfiddle.net/a0py6tvh/

Comment: Please [edit] the externally hosted code into the post; doing so will make sure it remains useful even if the link breaks. My script [is not allowed to do this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344512/4751173) because of potential licensing problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working [JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/Protozoid/pzs6mgd0/)

Added these properties to the `.popover` class styling

```
margin-left: 30px;
margin-right: 30px;
left: 0 !important;
```